# onBindViewHolder binding view inconsistently

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `ViewHolder` that is meant to appear differently depending on whether it is on the left or right side of a two-column `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`. Note the connector lines on either side of the view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="12px"
              android:layout_marginBottom="12px"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/citation_select_holder">
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/connector_line"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/citation_select_connector_right"/>


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="348px"
                    android:layout_height="104px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_background_white"
                    android:id="@+id/citation_select_citation_holder">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="28px"

        >
            <TextView
                    tools:text="123456"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/citation_select_item_number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/citation_select_citation_number_text"/>

            <TextView
                    tools:text="Pay by: Nov 18th, 2019"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/citation_select_item_due_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/citation_select_due_date_text"/>
            <TextView
                    tools:text="a category label"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/citation_select_item_category"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/citation_select_category_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
                tools:text="$10.00"
                android:textAppearance="@style/citation_select_item_cost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/citation_select_cost_text" android:layout_marginRight="28px"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/connector_line"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/citation_select_connector_left"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image: ViewHolder]

The connector line far from the side that the view appears on is meant to disappear when `onBindViewHolder` is called, and the margins updated accordingly.

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {

    holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.citation_select_connector_left).visibility = View.GONE
    val marginLayoutParams1 = holder.citationHolder.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
    marginLayoutParams1.setMargins(0, 12, 12, 12)
    holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.citation_select_holder).layoutParams =
        marginLayoutParams1

} else {

    holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.citation_select_connector_right).visibility = View.GONE
    val marginLayoutParams2 = holder.citationHolder.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
    marginLayoutParams2.setMargins(12, 12, 0, 12)
    holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.citation_select_holder).layoutParams =
        marginLayoutParams2
}
```

Scrolling is done exclusively via on-screen buttons in increments of six. The first two pages load normally:

[image: Desired Behavior]

But the pattern begins to break down at citation #14. Keep in mind that the citation numbers correspond are the view's position within the `RecyclerView`:

[image: Actual behavior]

What is happening to change the behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I know what can help you fix this. I presume that it is reusing the old view, as a `RecyclerView` should and nowhere in your code is there a line to set the visibility of the `connector` lines back to visible.

You should add to both your `GONE` visibilities also the code to set the other to visible:

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {

holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.citation_select_connector_right).visibility = View.VISIBLE
holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.citation_select_connector_left).visibility = View.GONE
val marginLayoutParams1 = holder.citationHolder.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
marginLayoutParams1.setMargins(0, 12, 12, 12)
holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.citation_select_holder).layoutParams =
    marginLayoutParams1

} else {

holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.citation_select_connector_left).visibility = View.VISIBLE
holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.citation_select_connector_right).visibility = View.GONE
val marginLayoutParams2 = holder.citationHolder.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
marginLayoutParams2.setMargins(12, 12, 0, 12)
holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.citation_select_holder).layoutParams =
    marginLayoutParams2
}
```

#### Additional explanation

The `RecyclerView` will reuse some old view, right? Well since both lines are `VISIBLE` at the start, you assume that's their default state. But when you set the lines to `GONE` you never put them back to visible, and thus if `RecyclerView` reuses that view, it'll not add the margin there and it will just be missing the connector line. You always want to have EVERY line of code in `onBindViewHolder` to have a matching line that reverts it.

Answer (score 3):

Vucko's answer is good, and the overall point (always update every component of your viewholder) is something you should absolutely do.

I wanted to add, however, that it appears as though you are not following the ViewHolder pattern correctly: your `onBindViewHolder()` method should never call `findViewById()`. Instead, your ViewHolder class should find each view once and then save references to them.

```
class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val connectorRight: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.citation_select_connector_right)
    val connectorLeft: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.citation_select_connector_left)
    // ...
}
```

And then you can use these fields directly inside `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
    holder.connectorRight.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    holder.connectorLeft.visibility = View.GONE
    // ...
} else {
    holder.connectorLeft.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    holder.connectorRight.visibility = View.GONE
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Agreed. Good point, I didn't focus on anything else other than fixing the RecyclerView :)